# Order_By custom date in peewee for SQLite

Tags: python, peewee

I made a huge misstake building up a database, but it works perfectly except for 1 feature. Changing  the program in all the places where it needs to be changed for that feature to work would be a titanic job of weeks, so let's hope this workaround is possible.

**The issue:** I've stored data in a SQLite database as "dd/mm/yyyy" `TextField` format instead of `DateField`.

**The need:** I need to sort by dates on a union query, to get the last `number` of records in that union following my custom date format. They are from different tables, so I can't just use rowid or stuff like that to get the last ones, I need to do it by date and I can't change the already stored data in the database because there are already invoices created with that format ("dd/mm/yyyy" is the default date format in my country).

This is the query that captures data:

```
records = []
limited_to = 25
union = (facturas | contado | albaranes | presupuestos)
    for record in (union
            .select_from(union.c.idunica, union.c.fecha, union.c.codigo,
                         union.c.tipo, union.c.clienterazonsocial,
                         union.c.totalimporte, union.c.pagada,
                         union.c.contabilizar, union.c.concepto1,
                         union.c.cantidad1, union.c.precio1,
                         union.c.observaciones)
            .order_by(union.c.fecha.desc())  # TODO this is what I need to change.
            .limit(limited_to)
            .tuples()):
        records.append(record)
```

Now to complicate things even more, the union is already created by a really complex `where` clause for each database before it's transformed into an union query.

So my only hope is: Is there a way to make `order_by` follow a custom date format instead?

To clarify, this is the simple transformation that I'd need the `order_by` clause to follow, because I assume SQLite wouldn't have issues sorting if this would be the date format:

```
def reverse_date(date: str) -> str:
    """Reverse the date order from dd/mm/yyyy dates into yyyy-mm-dd"""
    yyyy, mm, dd = date.split("/")
    return f"{yyyy}-{mm}-{dd}"
```

**Note:** I've left lot of code out because I think it's unnecesary. This is the minimum amount of code needed to understand the problem. Let me know if you need more data.

**Update:** Trying this workaround, it seems to work fine. Need more testing but it's promising. If someone ever faces the same issue, here you go:

```
.order_by(sqlfunc.Substr(union.c.fecha, 7)
          .concat('/')
          .concat(sqlfunc.Substr(union.c.fecha, 4, 2))
          .concat('/')
          .concat(sqlfunc.Substr(union.c.fecha, 1, 2))
          .desc())
```

Happy end of 2020 year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, if you want the dates to sort properly, they need to be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, which is the text format you should *always* use in SQLite (or something with the same year, month, day, order).

You might be able to do a rearrangement here using `re.sub`:

```py
.order_by(re.sub(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', r'\3-\2-\1',
                 union.c.fecha))
```

Here we are using regex to capture the year, month, and day components in separate capture groups.  Then, we replace with these components in the correct order for sorting.

Comment: Due to how peewee models work, `union.c.fecha` is not a string before it makes the query, so this workaround fails :(

Comment: You either have to change your model, or be able to do something like what my answer is suggesting (or use a completely raw SQLite query).  These are your only options unfortunately.

Comment: Actually you gave me a very good idea that I'm trying know, but I'd like your insight on it. See my Update on the question.

Comment: Yes, that should definitely work (if it does what its code seems to be saying).  Glad to help you.  Please store your date strings in an ISO format, year first, then month, then day.  This will avoid this problem in the future.  Keep in mind that SQLite doesn't actually have a date type, it just has a date _affinity_, which, however, just maps to a string/text column.

Comment: I'll still accept your answer, since you lead me the right way. Thank you, cheers! Edit: I definitely learnt the lesson, it won't happen again and I'll do the damn rework someday, but it'll take weeks because it's a huge ERP.